# Apache Thrift Simple server unable to run

Tags: thrift

I'm trying to run the simple java server/client Calculator server on Thrift tutorial with no success. I have downloaded the prebuilt thrift-0.14.2.exe and set the variable path, so far I'm able to generate the stubs from an IDL but the issue comes when trying to inialize the server and client. See below errors when I try to compile JavaServer using javac JavaServer.java

```
C:\Users\UserX\Desktop\ApacheThrift\thrift-0.14.2\tutorial\java\src>javac JavaServer.java
JavaServer.java:20: error: package org.apache.thrift.server does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.server.TServer;
                               ^
JavaServer.java:21: error: package org.apache.thrift.server.TServer does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.server.TServer.Args;
                                       ^
JavaServer.java:22: error: package org.apache.thrift.server does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.server.TSimpleServer;
                               ^
JavaServer.java:23: error: package org.apache.thrift.server does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer;
                               ^
JavaServer.java:24: error: package org.apache.thrift.transport does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory;
                                  ^
JavaServer.java:25: error: package org.apache.thrift.transport does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket;
                                  ^
JavaServer.java:26: error: package org.apache.thrift.transport does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerTransport;
                                  ^
JavaServer.java:27: error: package org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.TSSLTransportParameters;
                                                       ^
.\CalculatorHandler.java:20: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
                        ^
.\CalculatorHandler.java:28: error: package Calculator does not exist
public class CalculatorHandler implements Calculator.Iface {
                                                    ^
JavaServer.java:39: error: package Calculator does not exist
  public static Calculator.Processor processor;
                          ^
JavaServer.java:64: error: package Calculator does not exist
  public static void simple(Calculator.Processor processor) {
                                      ^
JavaServer.java:79: error: package Calculator does not exist
  public static void secure(Calculator.Processor processor) {
                                      ^
.\CalculatorHandler.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
  private HashMap<Integer,SharedStruct> log;
                          ^
  symbol:   class SharedStruct
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
  public int calculate(int logid, Work work) throws InvalidOperation {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Work
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
  public int calculate(int logid, Work work) throws InvalidOperation {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class InvalidOperation
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
  public SharedStruct getStruct(int key) {
         ^
  symbol:   class SharedStruct
  location: class CalculatorHandler
JavaServer.java:30: error: package tutorial does not exist
import tutorial.*;
^
JavaServer.java:31: error: package shared does not exist
import shared.*;
^
.\CalculatorHandler.java:23: error: package tutorial does not exist
import tutorial.*;
^
.\CalculatorHandler.java:24: error: package shared does not exist
import shared.*;
^
JavaServer.java:44: error: package Calculator does not exist
      processor = new Calculator.Processor(handler);
                                ^
JavaServer.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
      TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);
      ^
  symbol:   class TServerTransport
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
      TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);
                                             ^
  symbol:   class TServerSocket
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
      TServer server = new TSimpleServer(new Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
      ^
  symbol:   class TServer
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
      TServer server = new TSimpleServer(new Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
                           ^
  symbol:   class TSimpleServer
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
      TServer server = new TSimpleServer(new Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
                                             ^
  symbol:   class Args
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
      TSSLTransportParameters params = new TSSLTransportParameters();
      ^
  symbol:   class TSSLTransportParameters
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
      TSSLTransportParameters params = new TSSLTransportParameters();
                                           ^
  symbol:   class TSSLTransportParameters
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
      TServerTransport serverTransport = TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(9091, 0, null, params);
      ^
  symbol:   class TServerTransport
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
      TServerTransport serverTransport = TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(9091, 0, null, params);
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable TSSLTransportFactory
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
      TServer server = new TSimpleServer(new Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
      ^
  symbol:   class TServer
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
      TServer server = new TSimpleServer(new Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
                           ^
  symbol:   class TSimpleServer
  location: class JavaServer
JavaServer.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
      TServer server = new TSimpleServer(new Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
                                             ^
  symbol:   class Args
  location: class JavaServer
.\CalculatorHandler.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    log = new HashMap<Integer, SharedStruct>();
                               ^
  symbol:   class SharedStruct
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:48: error: illegal parenthesized expression
    switch (work.op) {
           ^
.\CalculatorHandler.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    case ADD:
         ^
  symbol:   variable ADD
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    case SUBTRACT:
         ^
  symbol:   variable SUBTRACT
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
    case MULTIPLY:
         ^
  symbol:   variable MULTIPLY
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    case DIVIDE:
         ^
  symbol:   variable DIVIDE
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
        InvalidOperation io = new InvalidOperation();
        ^
  symbol:   class InvalidOperation
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
        InvalidOperation io = new InvalidOperation();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class InvalidOperation
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
      InvalidOperation io = new InvalidOperation();
      ^
  symbol:   class InvalidOperation
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
      InvalidOperation io = new InvalidOperation();
                                ^
  symbol:   class InvalidOperation
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
    SharedStruct entry = new SharedStruct();
    ^
  symbol:   class SharedStruct
  location: class CalculatorHandler
.\CalculatorHandler.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
    SharedStruct entry = new SharedStruct();
                             ^
  symbol:   class SharedStruct
  location: class CalculatorHandler
46 errors
```

From my understanding I think I don't need to build anything with Visual studio since I have the .exe and the thrift libraries zip extracted here .What step could I have missed?

Comment: "*I think I don't need to build anything with Visual studio*" -- How could Visual Studio possibly help with a Java error?

Answer (score 0):

using intelliJ and maven resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> package org.apache.thrift.server does not exist

You are lacking the Thrift Java runtime libraries.